# Yellow substance dripping from aloe plant when cut

Tags: plant-health, aloe, poisons

I have been noticing a yellow, foul smelling liquid dripping out of my aloe plant when it is cut to obtain the pulp to add to juices etc.

Is this a disease or is this yellow substance normal.

[image: Yellow substance coming out of aloe]

[image]

Comment: Foul smelling is not a good sign - can you add a photo of the entire plant please, so we can judge how healthy it  is or isn't overall.

Comment: Ok sure, I will upload it.

Comment: I am not an expert.  Just wondering if the stem/leaf stalk when cut oozes a different coloured liquid as compared to cutting a leaf?

Answer (score 2):

I noticed this on my aloe cuttings as well and googled it. Turns out it’s aloe latex and although it’s not poisonous it’s a powerful laxative and if you plan to ingest the aloe pulp then you should first stand the aloe leaves in a tall glass and let the latex drip out. It’s bitter and harsh on the digestive system. I hope this helps!

Comment: Is it yellow and foul smelling on your cuttings

Answer (score 1):

The plant itself does not appear unhealthy, however, the cut stem you describe as foul smelling and yellow inside is abnormal. The pulp inside the leaf should be a clear greenish colour, not yellow. I would strongly suggest you don't use any of that leaf again in juices etc.

Whenever a leaf is cut, it's possible for pathogens to invade the cut area - if you have used the same stem previously to extract the pulp, then taken another section for use later, that could explain why it's foul smelling and yellow, i.e., it became infected after the first cut.

The cut leaf I can see in the image of the whole plant is presumably the one you used - whatever has caused the problem in that leaf might cause a problem with the whole plant over time, but at the moment, it looks fine.

Comment: Hello there, the pulp in side the aloe plant is all right but however, when I cut open the leaf, the yellowish, foul smelling liquid drips out.